# Is it possible to download and install a new geforce driver?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, video, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a laptop, the specs are given below

> Windows 7 Professional Service pack 1
>   Processor- Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU - M380 @2.53Ghz 2.53Ghz
>   RAM - 2.00GB
>   System type - 64bit OS
>   NVIDIA Version 341.44
>   GeForce GT 330M
>   DirectX runtime version: 11.0

When I was given this laptop I noticed that once in a while the laptop keeps going off. And then I checked the GeForce driver that was installed and it was for notebook laptop while the laptop I'm using is just a normal Samsung pc laptop.

So my question is: **If I install another driver (e.g GeForce 500 series on my laptop) will it work or do I need to buy anything?**

Comment: You should only install the driver if Nvidia specifically indcates the driver supports the 330M.  A driver that supports a GeForce 500 series and newer will not support the 330,

Comment: Down- & close-voters... we weren't all born with a computer in our hand, give the guy a break ;) The question boils down to 'what drivers should I get & who do I trust to get it right'. The answer is equally simple, **if** you already know, but not for a less computer-savvy user.

Comment: @Tetsujin **EXACTLY**

Comment: But what my question is aiming at is that, do we need to install it, for example GeForce 500 series or we need to buy the graphic card. I'm really not sure if this Geforce series are software or graphic cards

Comment: GeForce  is just a brand name. *Which* GeForce & precisely which OS is more important - that's why you use the NVidia app to figure out which drivers you need. If you install the wrong ones, your machine may not even be able to boot. Laptops very very rarely have the capability to add a different graphics card - you're stuck with the one it came with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notebook == Laptop; they're just marketing names for the same thing.

So long as your manufacturer hasn't locked out generic driver updates [which happens on some laptops, though idk about Samsung] then you should use NVidia's own tool to check & update your graphics drivers. If you are even vaguely uncertain about which to get, then that's the safest method.

You can find it at http://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/Scan.aspx or your country's equivalent via Google - 'nvidia drivers' should easily find it.

And just a word of warning - drivers are **always free**. Never be conned into anything that offers to sell them to you.
By the same token, never use any 3rd party software that promises to find outdated drivers on your computer - they are rarely anything more than snake oil & can even be harmful, by installing unnecessary or even wrong drivers.
Trust the companies that *actually made* your hardware - Samsung, NVidia etc.